# How to dry shirts using laundromats?

Tags: business-travel, laundry

I find the hotel laundry services a bit expensive so I was thinking about starting to use laundromats. However, I don't want to dry my business shirts using the dryers as they might get destroyed. What's the best was of drying shirts when using a laundromat? Bringing them back to the hotel? Or using the dryers?

Comment: How do you normally dry your shirts?

Comment: This question lacks a lot of technical details. What material are your shirts and do they have a finish you have to be careful with. What kind of machines do the laundromats have, that you are scared to use them?

Comment: Well really, you seem to have two choices: use the dryer, or hang them in your room. As you don't want to do the first, then you must do the second. But another option is to use a commercial laundry which might have a same-day service and iron the shirts too.

Comment: No-iron shirts like Brooks Brothers do fine when dried in a drier and hung up immediately when warm. If you have fancier shirts than that, the hotel costs shouldn't be much of an issue. Really old gas driers might be hard on clothes, but modern laundromat driers, even gas ones, shouldn't be.

Comment: In a pinch, you can dry your shirts in the rotor wash from your helicopter.

Answer (score 2):

Lay a towel down, lay your shirt on the towel, lay another towel on top.

Roll it up, put your weight on it (I find via knees best).

Unroll.

Request more towels from hotel and/or wait.

Repeat.

Done.

Comment: Alternative to step #3 - take your damp towels down to the laundromat and put them in the dryer for a little while ... ;)

Comment: Best put them in the dryer till dry, iron them there and fold them. Unless made of very sensitive materials, they will survive. It does require you to know how to iron them.

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ ... OP says they don't want to use dryers